# Xamarin Forms Button Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind my button to my command in my view model but it won't trigger when I click it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.UI.Views.AuthenticationPage">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button Text="Authenticate" Command="{Binding AuthenticateCommand}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Label Text="Locked" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Backend code:

```
public partial class AuthenticationPage : ContentPage
{
    public AuthenticationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new AuthenticationViewModel(this);
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My view model:

```
public class AuthenticationViewModel
{
    private ContentPage contentPage;

    public ICommand AuthenticateCommand { get; set; }

    public AuthenticationViewModel(ContentPage contentPage)
    {
        this.contentPage = contentPage;

        AuthenticateCommand = new Command(test, () => true);
    }

    private void test()
    {

    }
}
```

I had it working before but it stopped working after making a few changes. I don't think I need `INotifyPropertyChanged` for button commands, right?

Comment: Are you sure this is Xamarin? Looks more like WPF to me.

Comment: Yes Eminem, it's Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your Label is in the same row as the button and it overlapses it, so that the click/touch simply doesn't reach the button. Yes, you **don't** need to notify the property changes on the command, as long as you initialize it in the constructor / before the binding happens.

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.UI.Views.AuthenticationPage">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button Text="Authenticate" Command="{Binding AuthenticateCommand}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Label Text="Locked" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```